# How can I make my header completely inline using float?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML, and I am trying to figure out a way to make my logo, nav menu and social media icons one a single line.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
        <ul class="nav">
           <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
           <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
           <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="social-media">
       <a href="#"><img src="facebook.jpg"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="twitter.jpg"></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="pinterest"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to logo to the left, nav menu in the middle, and the social media icon to the right.

I just realized that I forgot to post my CSS:

```
div .h1 {
    float: left;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried so far? Can you post your current CSS?

Comment: Could you include some of your CSS? it also helps to include a jsfiddle for these types of questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is `text-align: justify`:

Take a look at this **<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3heK/2/)</kbd>**

Another good Tutorial for this effect is found on [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/).